# Make IntelliJ reformat the current line on line-completion

Tags: intellij-idea, reformat

Is there a way to have my line reformatted upon completing it in IntelliJ? *(For those familiar, this kind of feature is available on FlashDevelop.)*

Let's says I just entered this code in PHP:

```
$var=array("a","b","c");
```

Upon entering the semicolon, I would like the editor to reformat it to (or whatever my configuration states):

```
$var = array("a", "b", "c");
```

This auto-reformat trigger could also be executed on brackets and other line-terminators characters.

Comment: This is a missing feature for me too. I like typing fast, without caring for spaces, then si my line cleaned on completion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such feature in IDEA. You can use **Reformat Code** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>) action when needed.

Comment: After several more research, I didn't found anything that could do the job like in FlashDevelop... I'll have to investigate custom-plugin creation!

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do something like.

```
Go to where you want to insert ;
Tools/Start Macro Recording
Type in ;
Then select Code/Auto Indent Lines
Tools/Stop Macro Recording
Name the macro "reformat"
Now go to settings, Keymap, Macros, select "reformat"
Assign a keyboard shortcut of ;
```

You may have to play with it a bit to get your cursor in the right spot after the macro runs.

Comment: Code/Auto Indent Lines will not reformat code inside the line like Raphael needs (no spaces will be inserted).

Comment: @CrazyCoder, it work using _Reformat Code_ on a selected text-zone.
Unfortunately, mapping a macro that write a Semicolon on the Semicolon make no semi-colon outputted (v10.0.3).
And this is way too restrictive to map it on this key-stroke... I was more looking at a _PSI Structure_ based trigger...

But thanks for this introduction to the world of the Macros, I'll enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

This is based on [jhormans answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5793546/2454734) above and i know that the question is more than 6 years old. But IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.5 still does not have a feature that automatically reformats the current line when semicolon is pressed like VisualStudios.

The workaround is to create a macro as described by jhorman but after pressing ';' run Code -> Reformat Code. Then stop recording and under Settings/Keymap/Macros add the shortcut "Shift+Comma" to the macro. Now when typing the semicolon by pressing Shift + Comma in the code, the code will be reformated aswell. The only shortcoming: the whole code will be reformated each time Shift+Comma is pressed. This may take a second on large files.

This workaround will only work if you just have one line terminator like semicolon. To automatically reformat the code on multiple line terminators (closing brackets, semicolon, ...) you would need to add the shortcuts to "Settings" -> "Keymap" -> "Main Menu" -> "Code" -> "Reformat Code" directly. In this case there's no need to create a macro.

Just formatting the current line isn't possible as far as i know.